# i need to delete the phone number after the 'i'tag

Tags: node.js

[here you have a part of the html code of the website that i'm trying to grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o8NL.png)

i need to delete the phone number after the 'i' tag (`<i class=""fas fa-phone"></i>`) but i don't know how to do that, i need a solution who can work on all my address list

> ```
>    for(var i = 1; i < nombres; i++) {
>    const nom = await page.evaluate((i) => { return document.querySelectorAll('div.card-header > a > strong')[`${i}`].innerText}, i);
>    const adresse = await page.evaluate((i) => { return document.querySelectorAll('div.card-body > div')[`${i}`].innerText.replace(/\n/g, " ");}, i);
>    name.log(nom)
>    street.log(adresse)
>   }
> ```

after this, we have "nom" and "adresse" separated, i need to make like JSON format for make an excel with this. if anyone can help me that will be very nice, thank you.

Comment: Is it possible for you to change your html so that the phone number text alone is contained by an element you can select either by id, class, or attribute? That would make removing or changing the phone number text much simpler. Ex: `<span class="phone-number-to-delete">123-456-6161</span>`

Comment: the website is not mine, i can’t do that.

Comment: Can you add more of the surrounding html structure to your question? I see you selecting divs and classes, but I don't see those in the picture. Also, could you add them as text instead of a picture? Generally pictures of code are discouraged on StackOverflow. Thank you.

Comment: [You have more infos here](https://prnt.sc/128k59d)